# EKS - ALB ingress unable to annotate backend port for Target group(K8S)

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks

I have been using alb ingress to route traffic to my pods in backend but while annotating alb ingress I am **unable to annotate backend port** using `alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-port: 10987` only able to annotate protocol `alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTPS`.
By default it was taking port 1 as shown below[image]

but I need the port to be 10987. Is it a bug or do we have any fix for this?

Ingress yaml

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
  namespace: development
  labels:
    app: test-ingress
  annotations:
    # Ingress Core Settings  
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internal
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-name: test-alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-group-attributes: deregistration_delay.timeout_seconds=10
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/ip-address-type: dualstack
    # Health Check Settings
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-protocol: HTTPS
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-port: '10987'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-interval-seconds: '15'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-timeout-seconds: '5'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/success-codes: '200'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthy-threshold-count: '3'
    ## SSL Settings
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTPS":19065}]'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTPS
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-port: '10987'
spec:
    defaultBackend:
       service:
          name: some-test
          port:
             number: 10987
```